# Java, combobox warning unchecked?

Tags: java

I am getting a waring saying `unchecked` in the following code:

```
JComboBox<String> boxes[] = new JComboBox[3];
```

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about it in *Oracle Java Tutorial - Restrictions on Generics*

[Cannot Create Arrays of Parameterized Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html)

---

Directly from above tutorial where it is explained in detail:

You cannot create arrays of parameterized types. For example, the following code does not compile:

```
List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List<Integer>[2];  // compile-time error
```

The following code illustrates what happens when different types are inserted into an array:

```
Object[] strings = new String[2];
strings[0] = "hi";   // OK
strings[1] = 100;    // An ArrayStoreException is thrown.
```

If you try the same thing with a generic list, there would be a problem:

```
Object[] stringLists = new List<String>[];  // compiler error, but pretend it's allowed
stringLists[0] = new ArrayList<String>();   // OK
stringLists[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // An ArrayStoreException should be thrown,
                                            // but the runtime can't detect it.
```

If arrays of parameterized lists were allowed, the previous code would fail to throw the desired `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: Spot on. More details: the ArrayStoreException is thrown at runtime. The java runtime knows nothing of generics due to type erasure, so it can't distinguish between `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>`. They both look like plain old `ArrayList`.